# Problems with proving a lemma about function in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R, f \in C^{\infty}, f(0)=0$. Then i have to prove that  functions $f_{i}:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R, f_i \in C^{\infty}$ exist such that $f=x_1 f_1+...x_n f_n$ where $x_i$ are coordinate projections. I know that answer is $f(x)=\sum \limits_{i=1}^n x_i \int \limits_0^1 D_i(f(tx)) dt$, where $D_i$ are partial derivatives.

I try to prove it this way $f(x)=\int \limits_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}f(tx) dt=\int \limits_0^1 d_{tx}f(x)dt=\int \limits_0^1 \sum \limits_{i=1}^n tx_i D_i(f(x))dt=\sum \limits_{i=1}^n x_i \int \limits_0^1 tD_i(f(x))dt$, where $d_{tx}$ is a derivative in the direction of $tx$. Hovewer there seems to be an error, because it is not equal to the expression in the answer. Please help to understand this.

Answer (score 2):

The formula $$f(x)=\sum \limits_{i=1}^n x_i \int \limits_0^1 D_i(f(tx)) dt$$ is either incorrect or ambiguous. I would write 
$$f(x)=\sum \limits_{i=1}^n x_i \int \limits_0^1 (D_if)(tx)\,dt$$
to make it clear that we first take the partial derivative of $f$ and *then* plug in $tx$.

The error in your computation is here: 
$$\int \limits_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}f(tx) dt=\int \limits_0^1 d_{tx}f(x)dt$$
When we use the chain rule, the argument of $f$ should stay  the same, not change to $x$. Also, introducing $d_{tx}$ makes the computation less clear.

Here is what I would do. Let $u=tx$. By the chain rule, 
$$\frac{d}{dt}f(tx) = \nabla f(u) \cdot \frac{d u}{dt} = \nabla f(u)\cdot x = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i (D_if)(tx)$$
Hence,
$$f(x) = \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}f(tx) \,dt = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \int_0^1 (D_if)(tx)\,dt $$